# Dual Boot Windows Problem

Tags: system-installation

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu on my Samsung All-In-One computer. I've followed the instructions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) but I've hit a problem.

During the installation processes the documentation states:

```
Choose the first option, which should say "Install them side by side, choosing between them each startup".
```

But, I do not see that option. I'm on the "Installation Type" on the installation, but all I see is two options 1) "Replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu" or "Something Else". When I click "Something Else" I don't see any option that mentions installing them side by side. All I see is a screen asking me to partition.

What's the best way to dual boot from here? I have 500GB free space that I want to install Ubuntu on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to install ubuntu with windows is to partition it yourself when you do not have that option. It is in your link at the [this section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot#Manual_partitioning)

Also note that you need completely "FREE SPACE" in the partition table. Windows is still able to claim the free space as its own and make it unavailable for partitioning.

Comment: I had to partition the partition that had windows installed, which had 800gb free space. Once I done that, the option was available. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that the live environment does not recognize your windows 8 installation.
try these two things, im assuming that you are using a USB to load the live enviroment

1) re-do your live usb with linux live, use the most uptodate ISO of ubuntu (as older versions may not recognize win8)

2a) partition your HDD from windows so that some of the HDD is considered 'unallocated' or unformatted 
2b) use 'something else' and install ubuntu to the 'unallocated section'